# Angular router activates wrong route guard

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I'm having issues with Angular routing that don't seem to make much sense. With the following set-up, this outcome occurs...

- App loads at path `/`
- Auth guard runs
- Auth guard returns false as there is not yet a JWT in storage
- Redirection to `/login` works as expected.

However...

- Navigate directly to `/activate` (Route in the account module)
- Console logs that the auth guard is being run (Which shouldn't happen)
- Redirected to `/login`

I'm struggling to understand why auth guard is running for the `/activate` route when it's not a child of the dashboard layout.

App routes

```
 {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [DashboardGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'schedule',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('@libs/schedule').then(
            i => i.ScheduleModule
          ),
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Schedule'
        }
      },
      // Other feature modules omitted
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/schedule',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Account Routes

```
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'activate', component: ActivateComponent }
```

Auth Guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private router: Router,
    private accountService: accountService
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    console.log('Auth Guard Start'); // <-- This appears in console

    return this.jwtService.getToken().pipe(
      map(token => {
        if (!token) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
        // Attempt to populate the user using the token.
        this.accountService.populate();
        return true;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

App Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DashboardLayoutComponent],
  imports: [
    // .. other modules omitted
    AccountModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, DashboardGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Additional information

This happens when running in production mode only.

Augury reports that `/login` and `/activate` are both siblings of the `/` route. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LDY4.jpg

`@angular/core: 8.2.6`

`@angular/router: 8.2.6`

Comment: How are account routes connected to main routes?

Comment: Account routes are imported into the account module, which is imported into the app module.

Comment: Which means account routes ARE children of app routes.

Comment: Only one router should be imported for root. So I believe this to be incorrect. I will say that this happens when running in production mode and not in dev mode.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CJyKu8C

Here is how Augury interprets my routing. You can see that they are siblings, not children.

Comment: AuthGuard is on the root route.

Comment: @ritaj I don't know how that makes any difference or what you're implying. Yes it is on that empty path but it shouldn't be matched if navigating directly to /activate.

Comment: That's how Angular router works. Every  route is a child of `/`

Comment: Even after setting the dashboard path to a route of 'dashboard', the activate route is not not found by the router.

Comment: You're not helping yourself. Remove the guard from the root route, add it to the highest route you actually want to apply it to and you're golden.

Comment: Commenting out the auth guard to prevent it running still does not allow me to navigate directly to the /activate route. This is a fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was actually caused by my `ngrx-router` implementation where I was defining its initial state.

Originally initial state was set in the following way as suggested here - https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/835#issuecomment-369592809

```
export const routerInitialState: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl> = {
  state: {
    url: window.location.pathname,
    queryParams: getQueryParams(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    params: {}
  },
  navigationId: 0
}
```

This will not work in production builds. Navigating directly to a route like `/activate`, for example, causes a discrepancy between router state and angular router state, cancelling the navigation.

The correct way top set the initial router state is as follows...

```
export const routerInitialState: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl> = {
  state: {
    url: '/',
    queryParams: {},
    params: {}
  },
  navigationId: 0
}
```

With `initialNavigation: 'enabled'` in `app-routing.module`, the router state is updated at the earliest possible point and is synced with the angular router.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think, that clue for your problem is as follows:

You adding routes for accounting modules fisrt, and of course in that module you marking them as forChild.
Then, you added main AppModuleRouts. 
After your application was compiled and run - etire RouterTree includes all possible paths. So that, routes from AccountModule actually became a child routes.
So, as far as you applied canActivate: [AuthGuard] on an empty route - the most general of it could be - it fires every time.

Comment: Only one router should be imported for root. Account is a feature module and should be able to handle it's routing as I have it set up.

Comment: And I even do not want to argue with that. But the reason which cause your guard fires every time is written above.

Comment: So, as @ritaj has already written all your feature module routes became child....

Comment: But not a child of a route defined in my app routing module. So this still doesn't answer the question. Augury shows that dashboard, login and activate are all siblings. So what is it you are proposing?

Comment: The most brief proposal in your case is to move App routes on more level lower. It may be not clearest one but fastest for shure.

Comment: Please see here - https://imgur.com/a/CJyKu8C

Login and activate are siblings, not children.

Comment: I have to admit you were right. But, when i have created an app with similar routing scheme i've not met such a behaviour neither in dev nor in prod modes. It seems you need to share your app (part of it of course) so we can investigate details

Comment: Thank for your help all the same.